# sp_BlitzIndex "Missing Index" section has columns but no values/results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sp-blitzindex

when I run sp_BlitzIndex @Version = '7.5', @VersionDate = '20190427', on my Microsoft SQL Server 2017 v14.0.3048.4, I have some tables where the missing indexes reports one column `Finding` with the value "No Missing Indexes".  This is perfect.

But in many cases I have what appears to be result columns with no values. It looks like this:

```
Finding | URL | Estimated Benefit | Missing Index Request | Estimated Impact | Create TSQL
```

And there is nothing in the rows.  My fear is that I actually have some missing indexes but some wire is crossed and the output isn't being produced.  I have been using this tool for years and find it invaluable, so I want to be certain I am actually seeing the correct results.

Answer (score 4):

That just means SQL Server's not recommending indexes for that table, or the index recommendations aren't a significant benefit. We filter out trivially insignificant missing indexes, like those with a very low benefit that have only been run a few times.

If you'd like to try other scripts, you can use [any](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1634/using-sql-server-dmvs-to-identify-missing-indexes/) [number](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/tune-your-indexing-strategy-with-sql-server-dmvs/) of [them](https://www.sqlshack.com/collecting-aggregating-analyzing-missing-sql-server-index-stats/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification!